# Can't make a working jar file if all capital letters in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, capitalization

I just spent a little while learning the hard way that Gradle can't make a working jar file if the directory (and thus jar file) is labeled something LIKE_THIS.

Does anyone know why this is? I'm just picking up Java and would like to know why. I've heard it's bad practice to label packages with capital letters as well.

EDIT:

If the directory is all caps, I'd get `Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.HelloWorld` but it would work perfectly fine if it's lableded something `like_this`.

EDIT:

My directory structure after fixing the label was just from a tutorial, but here it is:

```
alexanders-mbp:VALID_JAVA alexanderkleinhans$ tree
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── net
│   │           └── petrikainulainen
│   │               └── gradle
│   │                   └── HelloWorld.class
│   ├── dependency-cache
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── VALID_JAVA.jar
│   └── tmp
│       ├── compileJava
│       └── jar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── net
                └── petrikainulainen
                    └── gradle
                        └── HelloWorld.java
```

Changing the directory to `something_else` and re-building makes everything work. BTW, no build errors.

EDIT:

I was following [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-our-first-java-project/) and couldn't get it to work so I finally cloned the [git-repo](https://github.com/pkainulainen/gradle-examples/tree/master/first-java-project) where I discovered my issue.

To run, I would do
`gradle assemble`
`gradle build`
`java -jar build/library/VALID_JAVA.jar`

(VALID_JAVA being the directory name and thus jar file name.)

Comment: Are you sure that this is a gradle issue? How do you invoke the application and how does your directory tree look like? Where is the jar file located? Which shell on which operating system are you using to launch the application?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a Gradle issue, which is why I ask.

Comment: The error message does not match your package structure: it looks like you try to launch `src.main.java.HelloWorld`, but the fully qualified class name is most likely `net.petrikainulainen.gradle.HelloWorld`. Try `java -classpath build/libs/VALID_JAVA.jar net.petrikainulainen.gradle.HelloWorld`. Note also, according to the tutorial, the gradle build creates a runnable jar file which you can launch like `java -jar NameOfJarFile`.

Comment: That totally work Andreas. Thanks! Post your answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: So specifying the class path did get it to work, but again, `java -jar NameOfJarFile` still had problems when it was all caps for some reason, but not when it was lowercase...

Comment: So even `java -jar build/library/VALID_JAVA.jar` did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you try to launch `src.main.java.HelloWorld`, but if you look at the sources from the GIT repository the fully qualified class name is `net.petrikainulainen.gradle.HelloWorld` (which also matches your directory structure).

To launch the application, use

```
java -classpath build/libs/VALID_JAVA.jar net.petrikainulainen.gradle.HelloWorld
```

Note also, according to the decription at the GIT repository, the gradle build creates a runnable jar file which you can launch like

```
java -jar pathToJarFile
```